# How to count Artist in ManyToMany Field in Django

Tags: python, django, model

**i want to count the number of videos made by a single artist so please tell me where am i wrong?**

Here is My code in admin.py File

```
class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'date_of_birth', 'artist_videos']
    def artist_videos(self, obj):
        count = 0
        for artistcount in Artist.objects.all():
            if artistcount.name == VideoList.artists:
                count = count + 1
        return count
```

And her is my code in models.py

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class VideoList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is simply, that you are checking the wrong thing. In the statement:

```py
    ...
    count = 0
    for artistcount in Artist.objects.all():
        if artistcount.name == VideoList.artists:
            count = count + 1
```

you are comparing a **string** to a django **queryset**. This will always be **False**.

You actually have the Artist object collected in **obj**, so you can rather use:

```py
class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'date_of_birth', 'artist_videos']
    def artist_videos(self, obj): # <-- mind the obj parameter!
        return VideoList.objects.filter(artists__name=obj.name).count()
```

This way you filter Videos with an actual Artist object.

Mind though, that I haven't checked in an actual project of mine, so I might be wrong :/

Best of luck!

[EDIT]
User @ruddra posted a better answer. Please consult his post as well! To summarize, the best way is to use M2M relation manager:

```py
    # previous code
    def artist_videos(self, obj):
        return obj.videolist_set.all().count()
```

Comment: but you gave me this answer not @ruddra and knowledge something which transfer from one person to an other only maters the one person who transfer's you the knowledge

Answer (score 2):

You can make a reverse query like this:

```
class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # rest of the code
    def artist_videos(self, obj):
        return obj.videolist_set.all().count()
```

For more information please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Answer (score 0):

Well make sure you have migrated you artist model.
check that by running following command.

```
python manage.py makemigrations 'Your app name here'
```

than

```
python manage.py migrate
```

After this try
import following models in your admin.py

```
import Artist
import VideoList

    def artist_videos(self, obj):
        count = Artist.objects.filter(name=VideoList.artists.name).count()
        return count
```

Do this and tell me.